# Windows XP TCP/IP No buffer space available

Tags: windows-xp, tcpip

I have isolated a problem down to this:

On Windows XP Pro, SP2 if one does an experiment where one tries to open TCP/IP sockets in a loop (bascially, listen port 7000, listen port 7001, etc.)

After approx 649 open sockets, one will start getting errors:  No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?)

The question is, what registry settings etc. does one edit to increase the number of listening sockets one can open before receiving this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look to this page: http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-tcpip-max-limit.html