# Windows XP SP3 TCP/IP No buffer space available

Tags: windows-xp, tcpip

I have the exactly same problem as here: [Windows XP TCP/IP No buffer space available](https://serverfault.com/questions/105677/windows-xp-tcp-ip-no-buffer-space-available)

> On Windows XP Pro, SP3 if one does an experiment where one tries to open TCP/IP sockets in a loop (bascially, listen port 7000, listen port 7001, etc.)
>
> After approx 649 open sockets, one will start getting errors: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?)

I've tried to edit the registry as described here http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-tcpip-max-limit.html I set MaxUserPort = 65534 and MaxFreeTcbs = 2000, but it didn't help.

What else can I do? I need 1000 server sockets.

Here is the error stack:

05.04.2012 10:23:57 java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): listen
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.listen(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:127)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:59)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:52)
    at channelserver.NIOAppServer.initSelector(NIOAppServer.java:40)
    at channelserver.NIOAppServer.(NIOAppServer.java:27)
    at channelserver.NIOServer.main(NIOServer.java:433)
 at channelserver.NIOServer.main(NIOServer.java:438)

Comment: Googling for the error, everything seems to refer to Java/JDBC. Is this a Java app you're writing? If so you may get a better response over at Stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes, this is Java application, but there is nothing about jdbc in error stack. Anyway, thanks for you help, I'll try to ask there

Comment: Check this out too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068423/java-net-socketexception-no-buffer-space-available-maximum-connections-reached

Comment: I've seen this, but found nothing suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone would face this problem too.
Finally it seemed to me that it's just WinXP's problem. I've tried the same code with more RAM - results were the same. But when I've tried it on Win7, everything worked fine even with 1200 sockets. 
So, WinXP is just not suitable for such tasks.